# How to look at a vertices neighbor and the weight of the edge between the two?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, dijkstra

I'm working on trying to implement Dijkstra's algorithm (in javascript) and I'm having some trouble in trying to figure out how to read a vertices neighbors and the weight of the edge between them.

I've created this graph here. Its nothing special, I plan on creating more graphs I just made this one for the initial test.

```
var graph1=
{
 A:{B:1, C:2},
 B:{A:1, D:4, E:1},
 finish: Infinity
 };
```

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: What trouble are you having? Can you show us the code you've written in your attempt to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you've given, to view a vertices neighbor would be `Object.keys(graph1['A'])` for instance. Further, the weight would just be something like `graph1['A']['B']`.

Try famliarizing yourself with [JavaScript Objects](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp)